# Setup multiple sites on local machine using XAMPP 2.4 not working

Tags: apache, multiple-domains

So i have 2 domain on the same host 
this is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/domain1"
    ServerName domain1.com.vn
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com.vn *.domain1.com.vn
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/domain2"
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com *.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

this is my host file

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost 
   127.0.0.1        domain2.com
   127.0.0.1        domain1.com.vn
```

when i go to domain2.com , it work but when i go to domain1.com.vn it go to domain2.com .

When i use www.domain1.com.vn then it's work and go to domain1.com.vn

So can you guy help me with this problem , i'm googling a lot but still can't find the problem

Answer (score 0):

Theres a syntax error in your configuration  for the domain2

`<VirtualHost *:80`  is missing a `>`

**UPDATE**

The reason its not working is because of the `*:80`  part as well.  The first one is okay, as its acting as a fallback, but then for the rest of the VirtualHost entries, you should specify the actual Virtual Host instead of *:80

```
<VirtualHost domain1.com.vn:80>
    ServerName *.domain1.com.vn
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/domain1">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And so on for domain2, etc...

Comment: fix it but still get the same problem

Comment: Its because Windows thinks that domain2 is 127.0.0.1 since it appears first in the hosts file.   The second entry is ignored. I don't know if virtual hosting with Windows is possible like that --- you have to use an IP that is delegated to you, not localhost (special case)